# Buffer/Capacity error saving dataframe as parquet in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having issues with PySpark writing a dataframe to Hadoop as partitioned parquet files.

This works well:

```
salesDfSpark.write.option("header",True) \
        .partitionBy("Country") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .csv("hdfs://master:9000/sales/{}_{}.csv".format(csvName,epochNow)) #Hadoop Namenode at port 9000
print("Sales Dataframe stored in Hadoop.")
```

This doesn't work:

```
salesDfSpark.write.option("header",True) \
        .partitionBy("Country") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .parquet("hdfs://master:9000/sales/{}_{}.parquet".format(csvName,epochNow)) #Hadoop Namenode at port 9000
print("Sales Dataframe stored in Hadoop.")
```

error using openjdk8:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:275)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.compress(Snappy.java:156)
```

error using openjdk11:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newLimit > capacity: (80 > 76)
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.createLimitException(Buffer.java:372)
```

Apart from changing java version I've tested both snappy-java-1.1.8.4 and snappy-java-1.1.4 with same result.
Anyone having any experience with this issue?

Edit:

This gives me the same error:

```
salesDfSpark.write.saveAsTable('salesDfSpark')
```

Output:

```
2022-06-12 10:35:29,468 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 1184) (worker2 executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newLimit > capacity: (144 > 112)
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.createLimitException(Buffer.java:372)
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:346)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.limit(ByteBuffer.java:1107)
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.limit(MappedByteBuffer.java:235)
    at java.base/java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.limit(MappedByteBuffer.java:67)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.compress(Snappy.java:156)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.SnappyCompressor.compress(SnappyCompressor.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.compress(CompressorStream.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressorStream.finish(CompressorStream.java:92)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory$HeapBytesCompressor.compress(CodecFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageWriteStore$ColumnChunkPageWriter.writePage(ColumnChunkPageWriteStore.java:168)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:59)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterBase.writePage(ColumnWriterBase.java:387)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreBase.flush(ColumnWriteStoreBase.java:186)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.flush(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:29)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:185)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:124)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:311)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: header with parquet? why?

Comment: 1. option("header",True)   ?
2. format(csvName,epochNow)  ?

Comment: Changing header to False didn't make any difference.

Comment: Spark ignores nonsense at times, true. But why would you?

Comment: I execute as per your suggestion but I still get the same error, thank you for the input. I also get the same error when saving as table, see edit above.

Answer (score 4):

I also had same error. Solution and error message too irrelevant, but following worked for me.

In my case java temp directory "/tmp" mounted to the server with noexec flag.
snappy-java library could not able to extract and execute its native library in temp directory and throws the mentioned stack trace because of the temp directory rights.

Solution is providing another directory which has execution right by using **"-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir"** configuration property.

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/my_user/temp_folder" my_app.py
```

Noexec flag also can be checked by using following command:

```
findmnt -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sequence worked for me:

1. I upgraded the versions of the parquet related dependencies and snappy-java dependency. [This made me run into - **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy**]
2. I then added this line in the Dockerfile which builds spark's distribution image - **apk add libc6-compat**